Find the points of conditional extremum of the function

Find the points of conditional extremum of the function $u= xy+yz$ subject to the condition $x^2+y^2=2, y+z=2, x>0, y>0$

I expressed $y=2-z$ and combined the two conditions into one $x^2+(2-z)^2=2$. Then I formulated the Lagrangian function $L=xy+yz+\lambda((2-z)^2+x^2-2)$ and, upon solving the system of equations:
$$
\begin{align}
L'_x=y+2\lambda x=0 \\
L'_y= x+z=0 \\
L'_z=y-2 \lambda(2-z)=0 \\
x^2+y^2=2 \\
y+z=2
\end{align}
$$
I identified a critical point $(-1,1,1)$. I am concerned that $x$ is negative, even though the condition states that $x$ should be greater than $0.$ I'm stuck and unsure about how to proceed. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance!

You're not considering the inequality constraints in your Lagrangian.
